# down indicator for google classroom api

Tags: google-classroom

It seems that Google Classroom API may be down this morning, is there any way to know that is the case (my code is failing, but I don't think it's my side.)

I can't find a down detector for Google Classroom API.

Comment: Found this, but it's not the API it's classroom itself. https://downdetector.com/status/google-classroom/

Comment: Have you tried the `Try this method` of any Classroom API available in their references? You could try [`courses.students.get`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/get) and see if it behavers properly. In terms of scripts, you can `try/catch` a sample classroom first and see if it returns a proper response.

Comment: Yes, but the issue was I had customers (of my chrome plugin) complaining it was not working for them, but I was not able to determine if it was just them, or google. It was not working for me either, but again, it could have been me/my region, or my provider. I was looking for a status page from Google, or a Twitter account, or anything like that - from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the status of their services using [Google Workspace Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/)

> This page provides status information on the services that are part of Google Workspace

[image: sample]

You could also see the history of issues at the bottom [link](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/products/3GoNVrVz48jeNZSyLJMV/history)

[image: history]

For under Google Ads, visit [Google Ads Status Dashboard](https://ads.google.com/status/publisher/)

For other issues, you can visit [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and search for related posts reported by other users.

#### Note:

- Seems like there were no recent outages on Classroom's side based on the status dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Google acknowledged an issue regarding the Classroom API not working. It took them 6 days for it to be fixed for our District, and I have no idea how widespread the issue was.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rbowe! This was helpful additional information.